# How to sort UL list by LI's data-title parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have this HTML code:

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li data-title="a">A</li>
    <li data-title="x">X <a href="...">blah</a></li>
    <li data-title="b">3</li>
    <li data-title="f">moo</li>
    <li data-title="m">foo</li>
</ul>
```

How can I sort this `<ul>` list using `jQuery` by data-title parameter? I found many questions about sorting UL by LI's content, but they aren't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JavaScript native function **[`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** for sorting

```js
// cache ul and li objects in variable
var $list = $('#mylist'),
  $li = $list.children('li');
// sorting list items using sort() based on data-title value
$li.sort(function(a, b) {
  // getting data-title attribute from dom object using getAttribute()
  var a1 = a.getAttribute('data-title'),
    b1 = b.getAttribute('data-title');
  //comparing values for sorting
  //return a1 > b1 || 0;
  //comparing values for sorting
  if (a1 > b1) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a1 < > b1) {
    return -1;
  }
  return ||0;
});
// updating sorted order sorted order
$li.appendTo($list);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mylist">
  <li data-title="a">A</li>
  <li data-title="x">X <a href="...">blah</a>
  </li>
  <li data-title="b">3</li>
  <li data-title="f">moo</li>
  <li data-title="m">foo</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @lshettyl : thanks for your suggestion , updated answer  :)

Comment: No need to detach and append. Only append will do. `$list.append($li);`